# How do i add another COUNT statement with different condition to sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

1st table: *duels*

```
| duelId | user1Id | user2Id | gameId | winnerId |
```

2nd table: *usergameprogress*

```
| usergameprogressId | userId | gameId | gameStar |
```

Given an `userId`, I would like to get duel count, gameStar, win count for each gameId.

Example return:

```
| duelCount | duelWinCount | gameStar | gameId |
```

I have managed to get duelCount, gameStar and gameId given a `userId` but I couldn't add `duelWinCount` to my query result. How do I do that ?

My query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(d1.duelId) AS duelCount,
    usergameprogress.gameId, usergameprogress.gameStar 
FROM 
    duels d1 
JOIN 
    usergameprogress ON (usergameprogress.gameId = d1.gameId) 
WHERE 
    d1.user1Id = "gkfurcwsi033qzxg0u2bmj1ekebsklej" 
    OR d1.user2Id = "gkfurcwsi033qzxg0u2bmj1ekebsklej" 
GROUP BY 
    usergameprogress.gameId
```

EDIT:
solved thanks to comment use sum instead of count

```
SELECT sum(case when d1.user1Id = 'gkfurcwsi033qzxg0u2bmj1ekebsklej' OR d1.user2Id="gkfurcwsi033qzxg0u2bmj1ekebsklej" then 1 else 0 end) AS totalDuelCount,sum(case when winnerId="gkfurcwsi033qzxg0u2bmj1ekebsklej" then 1 else 0 end) AS duelWinCount,usergameprogress.gameId,usergameprogress.gameStar FROM duels d1 JOIN usergameprogress  ON (usergameprogress.gameId = d1.gameId) GROUP BY usergameprogress.gameId
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Use `SELECT SUM(condition)` instead of `SELECT COUNT() WHERE (condition)` - such form allows to calculate a lot of separate SUM with different conditions.